# Why doesn't the managedObjectContext property synthesize its own instance variables ?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

appDelegate.h

```
    @property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

I had to do this in appDelegate.m

```
    @synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
```

I'm confused because according to apple

> Note: The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable
>   in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor
>   method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a readwrite
>   property, or a getter for a readonly property, the compiler will
>   assume that you are taking control over the property implementation
>   and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically. If you still
>   need an instance variable, you’ll need to request that one be
>   synthesized: @synthesize property = _property;

According to this it should create an instance variable as long as it created at least one accessor method. So does this mean that no accessors methods where created when I declared the property?  What is the reason. Please explain.

I'm assuming somehow the compiler knows that NSManagedObjectContext has accessor methods. So it didn't create any and therefor it didn't create instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't shown the code for the corresponding `.m` file, but I'm assuming you implemented the `managedObjectContext` property getter method programmatically. As the documentation says, "The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor method." But if you provide an implementation of the getter method for a `readonly` property, the compiler *isn't* synthesizing any accessor methods.

Comment: Ok, you are correct. I was looking at a video tutorial and missed the implementation of the getter method. I had assumed they didn't add it.

Answer (score -1):

As the documentation says...If you provide atleast one accessor method for  either setter or getter, its like telling the compiler...dont bother synthesizing this variable as I have some custom work to do with the setter/getter. Hence the compiler does not auto generate the _ivar. If you need the _ivar, you have to explicitly specify it and then proceed with your customer getter and setter. Its all about Objective C compiler doing things for you unless you say Don't bother...I know what I am doing.